# WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj 'RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h' file not found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

Working with:
Appium client 6.1.0
Appium Server 1.9.1
Xcode 10.0

Recently I’ve upgraded my MacOS to the latest Mojave version, unfortunately it somehow broke my iOS tests (I don't know how it's related but it is the only thing that changed).

When running any iOS test I’m encountering with this error message :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device. Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
```

I’ve navigated to node_modules⁩ ▸ ⁨appium⁩ ▸ ⁨node_modules⁩ ▸ ⁨appium-xcuitest-driver⁩ ▸ ⁨WebDriverAgent⁩ and opened WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj in Xcode then noticed that some files are missing ('RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h) thus the build fails, moreover it seems that the entire RoutingHTTPServer.framework is no longer recognised by the project.

I’ve tried almost any solution on the Web

- Followed the tutorial in the given error message
- Uninstalled & reinstalled Appium to the latest Beta version
- brew install carthage & ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d from the WebDriverAgent folder
- Tried resolving the build failure manually by opening the WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj in Xcode and re-attaching the missing RoutingHTTPServer/RoutingConnection.h file. Even copied the entire RoutingHTTPServer.framework

But nothing seems to be working, I would love to read any suggestion on how to solve this issue.

Cheers,

Comment: I think something is broken in the latest version of the Appium GUI app. Why don't you use an older version of the appium? Say: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

First enter the path of WebDriverAgent in terminal,
which is usually

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
```

Then input this

`./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d`